# Hardening uploads folder in IIS breaks images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, web-config

My site loads a bunch of images from the uploads folder, using direct URLs, such as:

http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/some.image.png

I'm trying to figure out a remote script execution issue, and one of the things recommended on https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress is to prevent script execution in the uploads folder, using the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Kill PHP Execution
<Files ~ "\.ph(?:p[345]?|t|tml)$">
   deny from all
</Files>
```

My site is running on IIS, so to acheive the same result, I removed the PHP handler for the uploads folder and all it's subfolders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <remove  name="php-7.1.7" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, if I use the web.config file, loading an image using a direct URL leads to a http 500 error. Consequently, themes don't load properly.

How would I go about preventing PHP script execution in the uploads folder, without breaking static file loading?

Adding `<add name="StaticFile" />` below `<remove  name="php-7.1.7" />` makes no difference.

Comment: This question was originally asked at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304762/hardening-uploads-folder-in-iis-breaks-images with no response. Hoping it will do better on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a web.config inside upload folder and paste in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read"> 
         </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```